# How to make a table with "irregular" columns in PHPWord?

Tags: php, phpword

In PHPWord it is easy to create a table like this:

[Simple Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48dAj.png)

but I don't understand how one can build a table with "irregular" columns, like the following:

[Irregular Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRQys.png)

In Word/LibreOffice I can do this first by merging all the cells of the row and then split them manually. In this way they become "indipendent" to the other cells of the table.

In PHPWord I can add all the cells but they will be the same width of the others. I think I could do it by creating a full-width cell and then add a nested table to it, but it seems like a trick to me and I would like to know if there is a cleaner solution.

Has anyone had the same problem before?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a bug in PHPWord, for which I provided a patch: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/2037